# S3 permission problems

Tags: python, amazon-s3

When I run this code:

```
conn = S3Connection('xyz','zyx')
conn2 = S3Connection('xxx','xyz')

srcBucketName = 'name1'
dstBucketName = 'name2'
srcBucket = conn.get_bucket(srcBucketName);
dstBucket = conn2.get_bucket(dstBucketName);

keys = srcBucket.get_all_keys(max_keys = 5, prefix='path/to/file')

for k in keys:
  print 'Copying ' + k.key + ' from ' + srcBucketName + ' to ' + dstBucketName

  t0 = time.clock()
  dstBucket.copy_key(k.key, srcBucketName, k.key)
  print time.clock() - t0, ' seconds'
```

I am being returned this error:

```
3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>734BB799C0FA1C7A</RequestId><HostId>y9WRn7lb3BDqbLurW5q1EsKz+FptqXgVxeIgNbWrEBshew7CQ0w6Lg+yjjd1Lqfe</HostId></Error>
```

(from another StackOverflow question)

I am able to download these files from the srcBucket using the keys I inputted into python. And I have write access to the dstBucket.

The srcBucket and dstBucket are accessed with different keepers which I have.

Does anyone know why I might have to do to gain access to copy over files from one bucket to the other?

Comment: Are you connecting to the correct region endpoint?  Which region is your bucket located in? If you're not specifying the region when you create your connection then I believe it defaults to us-east-1, and if that's not where your bucket is located then it will likely throw an error when you try to do anything with it.

Comment: My region is us-east-1, and the above script works if I change my bucket. So I think it might be a permissioning problem with the bucket I want to copy.

Comment: The account generating the copy request must have permission to read the source bucket and write to the target.